# TextView moves one line down when text changes programmatically

Tags: android, textview

This is a simple shell app that will display number of files in data/app folder when button is clicked the textviews are aligned as they should be, but when the button is clicked the textview that displays the number of files is moved down one line. Why?

Here is the code and the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:text="Button" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/user_apps" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
 package rs.test.rootapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class RootAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String command[]={"su", "-c","ls /data/app | wc -l"};
                Shell shell = new Shell();
                String text = shell.sendShellCommand(command);
                setNewTextInTextView(text);
            }
        });

    }

    public void setNewTextInTextView(String text){
        //TextView tv= new TextView (this);
        //tv.setText(text);
        //setContentView(tv);
        TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(text);
    }
    }
```

Screenshots:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgYoF.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OjB6.png]

Comment: change the width of your textview

Answer (score 1):

set the text in textview after done the trimming operation on it,may be this will work, try it

```
tv.setText(text.trim());
```

Comment: I will try this to, looks simpler than replace

Comment: I would like a vote too since I helped, I voted for your answer ;P

Comment: Answer does not give reason, my answer gave the reason and your just showing an alternate way... Additionally your trim it working on the output in ways which may not be desired... he only wanted the new line  off and only in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

With looking very quickly it seems like the return from the command is coming with the text.. Try and replace the new line in  `text` before setting the text in the TextView.

Comment: the return of `shell.sendShellCommand(command);` is adding a new line or that would be my guess...

Comment: And how can i remove that new line?

Comment: With a replace or a substring.... use your head. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158123/java-android-appending-a-newline-using-textview

Comment: I finaly get it. Thanks for help. This is what i did. String text2 = text.replace("\n" , "");