# How to solve TextView using append method unable to add new text value

Tags: java, android

```
value = et1.getText().toString();
budget = Integer.parseInt(value);
description = et2.getText().toString();
et1.getText().clear();
et2.getText().clear();

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0)
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putInt("Budget”， budget);
edit.putString("Description", description):
edit.commit();

MainClass
TextView budgettv;

budgettv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.budgettv);
budgettv.append(budget + " Description: " + description + "\n");

xml
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/budgettv"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I'm using editText to enter the value and display entered value in budgettv. I want to add new text in next line but when I using append it's overwriting the old value. How can I add the new value without replacing the old value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158123/java-android-appending-a-newline-using-textview/6158168

Comment: Your code snippet is working fine, can you show your full code?

Comment: @majuran If I'm using SharedPreferences to pass the value of EditText, if it possible to overwrite the old value?

Comment: I think, no need the help of SharedPreferences for passing values inside an activity. Can you show your edittext code?

Comment: I already renew my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to append data as below

```
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder(budget);
    sb.append(" Description: " + description );
    sb.append(System.getProperty(System.lineSeparator()));//Hear for new line
    budgettv.setText(sb);
```

Comment: I used SharedPreferences to store and pass EditText value into other Activity. Is there any method not to overwrite the old value of budgettv TextView?

Comment: you can pass through intent putExtra()

Comment: Can provide me some example? Just now I changed to use Intent but my TextView still cannot append new text inside.